Model intercomparison with no ground-truth labels
The domain is weather modeling. I've got 4 different models, one of which is mine, while the other 3 are independent models which I believe to be relatively skillful (i.e., much better than random). Each model predicts a single value at each of 1000 spatial locations of interest (I'll call them nodes). Sadly, the ground-truth value at each node is unmeasurable, so there's no way to definitively say which model is best.
However, I can tell that my model's predictions (model A) have a better correlation with the rest of the models than any other model does:




A
B
C
D




A
1
0.636338
0.571829
0.569591


B
0.636338
1
0.251786
0.283723


C
0.571829
0.251786
1
0.299746


D
0.569591
0.283723
0.299746
1



Model A is better at predicting model B than any other, and same for A vs. C and A vs. D. Since every model's predictions are a combination of some "true" signal and some noise/error, I hypothesize that my better correlation across the board means my model is likely capturing more "true" signal and less noise than any other models.
Is this a valid conclusion? If so, is there a way to quantify it, or a reference I could cite to back up this claim?

+1, interesting question, Will also note for readers that a related question for assessing performance of a single model can be found here, though obviously having multiple models makes this a different question.

I agree with the "no" answer. I think what you need is additional data that is somehow related (by theoretical knowledge or experience) to the predicted truth, so that you can use that to indirectly compare your models. This will involve assumptions that are hard or impossible to check, but at least it can give you some indication.

Suppose you have three measures, A, B, and C. Measure B is "mostly correct", and measure A is highly correlated with it. Measure C is "exactly correct", and has lower correlation with Measure B than Measure A does.
In this scenario, Measure A might be more highly correlated with both B and C, than B is with A and C, or than C is with A and B. That doesn't necessarily mean it's "more accurate", as the correlation might be coming from things that are wrong in the first place. If Measure C is truly exactly correct to begin with, there is no reason we should prefer Measure A just because it also shares some correlation with Measure B, which has some errors to begin with.
That said, I think it is generally desirable to correlate well with measures that are generally correct. It would probably take a specific set of errors to improve correlation specifically among the "incorrect" items, particularly when the underlying measures are good. But in general, I don't think we can conclude that a model which correlates with other models is necessarily more "correct".

Is Model intercomparison with no ground-truth labels a good idea?
No. Let me give a counterexample.
Given you search models giving directions.
Now you have (hidden) ground truth A giving direction (0,1)
You have two models B (-1,0), C (1,0).
The correlation between B and C (scalar product) is -1.
Now you come up with a model D (0,-1) which  at least manages to have a higher correlation of 0 with B and C.
Does it mean that D aligns better with ground truth? No, the correlation between A and D is worse, -1.
So without knowing ground truth you can get it totally wrong by just improving correlation (a form of scalar product).
Surely, this example is extreme. However, it can occur also at other levels of correlation. You need to improve correlation with ground truth prediction (end to end) not correlation with something which tries to be close to ground truth (but is arbitrarily wrong, because no ground truth was provided).
In a metaphoric description you run the risk of "running in circles" when you accept only optimizing for high correlation, but never look at ground truth: when you do that you may get closely related models all making only small errors but in the end you turn in a cricle and loose direction (since you never looked for a land mark, the ground truth)!
PS: For some unsupervised settings like clustering there is no label data. It turns out that these unsupervised methods cannot be evaluated without getting ground truth on e.g. clusters. You can do that with "external evaluation metrics" (in the case of clustering it would be v2 score or f1 score based on labels for the question "do two entities belong in one cluster or not?"). So for evaluation you need ground truth which is collected in a systematic way. There is some ideas about "internal evaluation metrics" which measure the compactness of clusters -- but you can have totally wrong compact clusters - when you compare to ground truth ...

your example was illustrative, thank you. I believe it holds in general even when all models are positively correlated with ground truth, not just orthogonal. The better correlation with other models tells us our model is some bounded distance from "the middle" of the other models' estimates, but there is no guarantee that middle is nearer to ground truth.

If we assume the other models' errors are randomly distributed around the ground truth, then it becomes more likely that the "middle" is a good estimate, but that's a difficult assumption to make. Many real-world models are consistently biased in the same directions because they share input data sources or physical assumptions.
